# How to generate a violation caused by 'novtable' in MSVC?

Tags: c++

Since CBase have pure virtual function, I can not create an instance of it.
How can I generate a violation through 'novtable' in this case?
If no way to do so, should 'novtable' be applied to all abstract classes?

No violation in this snippet:

```
struct __declspec(novtable) CBase
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
};
struct CSub: public CBase
{
    CSub() {    this->f();  }
    void f() {  printf("inside CSub::f()"); }
};
void TestVTable()
{
    CBase* pBase = new CSub(); 
    pBase->f(); 
}
```

Comment: thanks for editting, I could not figure out how to make it look right.

Comment: You're welcome. Is this your whole code? I mean, is `TestVTable` invoked somewhere? And did you try to explicitly call `f()`, not only causing call from the struct's constructor?

Comment: I just figured it out: in CBase(), do this: ((CBase*)this)->f();

Answer (score 2):

To violate this, you need to "invoke" the virtual mechanism.

First of all, the object should be created dynamically, because otherwise the function, that will be called, is the function, defined in the object's class. In this case - for sure it will be `CBase::f()`, so there's no need from access to the virtual table.

And second, you need explicit call to the function, because if the call is from the constructor, `f` is "resolved" at compile time as it's for sure, that the called `f` function will be `CBase::f()`. So, again - there's no need from access to the virtual table here.

So, for example, to violate this, you need to "use" the virtual mechanism, for example like this:

```
void TestVTable()
{
    CBase* Base = new CBase();
    Base->f();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kiril, that does creates an violation. I'll edit the question a bit, see if you can still create the violation. The editted one is the one I originally wanted to ask.

Comment: I editted the question just to make it make more sense, and to make the answers to it more helpful to folks.

Comment: @Rio - but the code, you have posted now (after the edit) should really be perfectly valid, AV should not be received. `__declspec(novtable)` is for the base class and your object is from a derived one. The code is perfectly fine. And as I said about your solution - you're trying to call pure virtual function, that's why the program crashes. If you remove the `__declspec(novtable)`, it will still crash. If you remove the `=0` and try without `__declspec(novtable)`, it will not even link.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found to generate a violation is listed below.
Two keys here:
1. f() must be called inside base constructor
2. 'this' must be casted.
It's hard because abstract class has no instance(of it's own, not it's subclass).

```cpp
struct __declspec(novtable) CBase
{     
    CBase() 
    {   
        ((CBase*)this)->f();    
    };
    virtual void f() = 0; 
}; 
struct CSub: public CBase 
{     
    void f()  {  } 
}; 
void TestVTable() 
{    
    CSub();      
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you need. This code will crash for sure(in debug mode, I guess it's undefined behavior in release), even without the `__declspec` - you're calling a pure virtual function. Actually, I have never used `__declspec(novtable)` and I'm not sure I know what is its idea, so this may be the answer, you're looking for. I just notice that.

Comment: Without novtable, exception says "pure virtual function call", while with novtable, it says "Access Violation". I still think novtable should be applied to all abstract classes. What do you think?

Comment: Honestly - I don't know, sorry. But what I think is, that you'r right, just the call to pure virtual function scared me a little. I'd try with second function, that is not pure virtual (and still leave `f` to be pure virtual). But I can't try now, as I have only gcc (at work)

Answer (score 0):

The virtual member need not be abstract - non-abstract will do.

```
struct __declspec(novtable) Struct
{
    virtual void DoStuff() {}
};

int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv[]*/)
{
    Struct* object = new Struct();
    object->DoStuff(); // crashes here
}
```

The whole point of `novtable` is that when it is applied to `class X` the constructor of that `class X` will not set the vtable pointer to `class X`'s vtable. That's all. So the crash will happen in any case when a virtual method is called on `class X` with `novtable` declspec such that there's no `class Base` without `novtable` declspec that `class X` inherits from, which would have the same virtual member function as the one being called. If such `class Base` exists then a wrong (not most derived) member function might be called. if no such class exists a crash will occur.

Comment: Why not default all abstract classes to novtable? This is the key question behind this discussion.